# Where I can download compiler for C# 4.0 without Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, c#-4.0

I know for CTP VS 2010 Images, but can I download only .NET Framework 4.0 and C# compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the VS 2010 CTP is only available as a VM image.  I do not believe Microsoft released an installer for VS.  One is definitely not available for a standalone CLR/SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Not at this time. Guessing maybe when the Betas start shipping.

Answer (score 3):

The .Net 4.0 redistributable is not available yet.

Answer (score 2):

Funny, I'm trying to [extract it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636850/register-dll-in-gac-without-assembly-manifest) from the VHD as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

As stated it's not available without the VHD. The reason for this is (I'm guessing) because:

1) MS want you to go through the pre-installed tutorials on the VHD to give design feedback.

2) MS doesn't want to have to do the extra work needed to get the installer working on all supported OSs.

Comment: Regarding "All supported OSs" - you mean "Microsoft Windows", right?

Comment: There are a ton of Microsoft Windows's.  Do you have any idea how many different configurations these people have to support?

Comment: About as many as different price points of Windows that they arbitrarily come up with, so it's a self-inflicted problem.

Comment: What if I said to you: "I've got this new code that I've written which I'm not going to give you because I haven't translated it into every language in the world."