# Register DLL in GAC without Assembly Manifest

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, gacutil

I have a DLL I wish to register with my GAC.  I enter the command:

```
gacutil /i c:\temp\msvcr100.dll
```

and I get the error:

```
Failure adding assembly to the cache:   The module was expected to contain an as
sembly manifest.
```

All I have is the DLL.  Is there a way to create / fake / bypass it?

For those interested, I am attempting to extract the Visual Studio 2010 & .NET 4.0 CTP from the VHD and run it on my physical box.  As a side note, has this been attempted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this actually a GAC-able DLL? It doesn't seem like it. Maybe it's just reg-able? Why do you want to GAC it?

Comment: I think so, but not sure. I got an error that said the file wasn't installed on the computer, and I had pulled it out of a VPC's System32. Just putting it into my system32 didn't work.

Comment: This is the C++ runtime library DLL, if I'm not mistaken, written in native code, and not GAC-able. I think you are going to hit quite a few hurdles trying to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish. Try sticking it in the bin folder or maybe registering it with regsvr32 or regsvcs?

Answer (score 2):

"For those interested, I am attempting to extract the Visual Studio 2010 & .NET 4.0 CTP from the VHD and run it on my physical box. As a side note, has this been attempted?"

FYI - At this point there is a full ISO image of Beta 1 you can download and legally run on your desktop if you want.

[VS 2010 beta 1 on MSDN](http://www.vistadb.net/blog/post/2009/05/17/visual-studio-2010-beta-1.aspx)

It is only for MSDN subscribers at this point though.  Will be added to Microsoft downloads later.

EDIT:  It is now open for all to download

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this with (apparently) corrupt dlls (I assume failed copies from USB drives).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the same process is done when you drag and drop to C:\Windows\assembly?

Comment: Yep, same error. Though this time it's in a nicer-looking but un-copy-and-pasteable GUI dialog.

Comment: Ah damn. Well good luck with your hacker and make sure to report back on your results!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that "extract[ing] the Visual Studio 2010 & .NET 4.0 CTP from the VHD" doesn't violate the license agreement?  If Microsoft wanted you to "run it [VS2010] on my physical box", they would have just made it available as a noraml install.

Comment: I dunno, they're pretty much all the same.  I don't think it constitutes reverse engineering...

Answer (score 0):

If you can create the manifest (I'm not sure what one should look like) it's easy enough to just load the DLL into Visual Studio's resource editor (File->Open->File->[select dll]->[click down chevron on the Open button]->Resource View) and just add the manifest to the dll.