# Can I write the code based on .NET Framework 4.0 without vs 2010?

Tags: c#, .net

I downloaded and installed the .net framework 4.0, but I didn't install VS 2010, because VS 2010 require the high-performance computer hardware. I have no but I expect to taste the C# 4.0 feature.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say it requires that much power; I run it in a VM on my laptop, with no GPU etc - works... acceptably...

Answer (score 4):

you need the .net 4.0 compiler, which at the moment is only available with vs2010.

This thread might answer your question 
[Where I can download compiler for C# 4.0 without Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591726/where-i-can-download-compiler-for-c-4-0-without-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: @bruce If you have installed framework 4.0 then you should be able to compile C# code using the C# complier in the 4.0 framework folder but you will have to using command line.

Comment: Really? I will try to do it following your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET framework client profile includes the compiler (csc.exe). For example, on my machine, it's at:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.20506\csc.exe
```

The 32-bit version is at:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.20506\csc.exe
```

If you're familiar with the command-line compiler syntax, most applications can be written just using it, notepad and referencing the appropriate assemblies. It won't be a terribly pleasant experience though.